# Required privilege not held returned by CreateFile

Tags: windows, winapi

While trying to open a file on Samba from a Win32 application running on Windows Server the function CreateFiles returns an invalid handle and the error code is 0x522 (ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD) is there a way to inquiry the system on which provilege is missing for that particular file?

I've enabled some security privileges after impersonating the logged user (which should be the admin): SE_SECURITY_NAME, SE_BACKUP_NAME and SE_RESTORE_NAME, but that doesnt work.

I just need read privileged over the file and I'm submitting the following options to CreateFile:

```
 hSrcFile = CreateFile (sourcePath, READ_CONTROL | ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);
```

Some other probably not very useful information:

- The logged user can open the file using any random application, like
  notepad.
- If the process create a new file in the samba folder then it can also
  open it without problems, the issue seems to affect files already
  created before the program starts.

Any suggestion? Thanks

**EDIT 1**

To configure the SE_SECURITY_NAME flag I'm taking the Process token with `OpenProcessToken`, then using [this function from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecAuthZ/enabling-and-disabling-privileges-in-c--) to enable the privileges.

I've also attempted to use the token from `LogonUser` while loggin as admin to set the privilege, but in this case the [MSDN funtion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecAuthZ/enabling-and-disabling-privileges-in-c--) seems to fail with error ACCESS_DENIED. Doing the same thing after duplicating the token with DuplicateToken (and SecurityDelegation flag) do not work either.

I've verified the return value of `AdjustTokenPrivileges` while setting SE_SECURITY_NAME and the function do not fail. I can call `CreateFile` to open the file without the flag ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY, but then I can't use the file handle to call `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` since the function fails with ACCESS DENIED, not sure if this is related to ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY or not.

**EDIT 2**

I'm performing the following steps to enable SE_SECURITY_NAME and then use CreateFile:

- Obtain the process token with `OpenProcessToken` (flags TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY) and call `AdjustTokenPrivileges` with SE_SECURITY_NAME,SE_BACKUP_NAME and SE_RESTORE_NAME. (After obtaining the proper LUID with `LookupPrivilegeValue`). The error code returned by the function is 0x0.
- Obtain the thread token with `OpenThreadToken` (flags TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY) and call `AdjustTokenPrivileges` with SE_SECURITY_NAME, SE_BACKUP_NAME and SE_RESTORE_NAME. (After obtaining the proper LUID with `LookupPrivilegeValue`). The error code returned by the function is 0x0.
- Call CreateFile with `CreateFile(pathTofile, READ_CONTROL | ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTIC,NULL)` the function returns 0x522: PRIVILEGE NOT HELD. The pathToFile have a format like "\192.168.0.0\folder\file.txt"

Hope this clarify a bit the flow, the code to enable the Privileges is:

```
bStatus = LookupPrivilegeValue (NULL, privilegeStr, &luid);
if (!bStatus)
{
    dwStatus = GetLastError();
   // do stuff
}

ZeroMemory (&tp, sizeof (tp));
tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

/* Adjust Token privileges */
bStatus = AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES),
    &oldtp, &dwSize);
dwStatus = GetLastError();
if (!bStatus || dwStatus != ERROR_SUCCESS )
{
    //do stuff, print error etc.
}
```

where privilegeStr is for example SE_SECURITY_NAME

**EDIT 3**

In the hope to provide an all-inlcusive example of code that reproduce the problem and thus maybe getting a possible solution for it, I've prepared this ugly code snippet:

```
HANDLE hToken;
bStatus = OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES |
    TOKEN_QUERY, TRUE, &hToken);

LUID luid;
LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_SECURITY_NAME, &luid);

TOKEN_PRIVILEGES    tp = { 0, };
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES    oldtp = { 0, };
DWORD               dwSize = sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES);

ZeroMemory(&tp, sizeof(tp));
tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

/* Adjust Token privileges */
bStatus = AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES),
    &oldtp, &dwSize);
dwStatus = GetLastError();
if (!bStatus || dwStatus != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    //Print error.
}

PRIVILEGE_SET privSet;
ZeroMemory(&privSet, sizeof(PRIVILEGE_SET));

privSet.PrivilegeCount = 1;
privSet.Control = PRIVILEGE_SET_ALL_NECESSARY;
privSet.Privilege[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
privSet.Privilege[0].Luid = luid;

BOOL bResult;
PrivilegeCheck(hToken, &privSet, &bResult);

fprintf(stderr,"Status bool: %d, attr value:0x%x, error code: 0x%x\n", 
    bResult,
    privSet.Privilege[0].Attributes,
    GetLastError());

hSrcFile = CreateFile (sourcePath, READ_CONTROL | ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);

if( hSrcFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
{
    fprintf(stderr,"CreateFile error 0x%x\n", GetLastError());
}
```

The output is `Status bool:1, attr value:0x80000002, error code: 0x0` followed by `CreateFile error 0x522`.

Does this example confirms that SE_SECURITY_NAME is enabled but `CreateFile` still fail? Anything else is needed? Additionally:

- I can open any other random file on the local disk with `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY`
- The file that fails to access is on SAMBA, as explained in the very first line of my question, does this have any relevance on the way those attributes have to be configured? It seems so, but don't know how.

Comment: for `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY` you need have `SE_SECURITY_NAME` privilege. this is common, not for this concrete file. are you really need access sacl ?

Comment: [SACL Access Right](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecAuthZ/sacl-access-right) - *The `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY` access right controls the ability to get or set the SACL in an object's security descriptor. The system grants this access right only if the `SE_SECURITY_NAME` privilege is enabled in the access token of the requesting thread.*

Comment: @RbNm I've already set SE_SECURITY_NAME. If I don't provide the flag ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY to CreateFile the functions return an access denied error.

Comment: and how you set `SE_SECURITY_NAME` ? i almost sure that you fail set it. may be because your user simply not have this privilege. and you really need access SACL ? if you got access denied - this is because you have not required access to file

Comment: also as side note `STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ == READ_CONTROL`, `CreateFile` always implicit add `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES | SYNCHRONIZE` to access mask. so you if you ask only `READ_CONTROL |  ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY` in call `CreateFile` - effect will be the same.

Comment: Thanks @RbMm , adding some more information in the question itself, perhaps this will help.

Comment: are your token have `SE_SECURITY_PRIVILEGE` ? are you check result of `AdjustTokenPrivileges` ? i sure that you got `ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED` and again i can not understand - are you need access SACL ? *Attempeting to call CreateFile without ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY do not work* - i complete dont understand this. if you got access denied from `CreateFile` - how add `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY` (so request even more access) can help here ?

Comment: Sorry I misread the logs and wrote something wrong: CreateFile actually works without ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY, please refer to the edit for a clarification.

Comment: return value of `AdjustTokenPrivileges` have no sense at all. you need check `GetLastError` after call this api. i sure `ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED` here

Comment: and agai and again - you need access sacl ?

Comment: So why the function is returning a return value if checking it have no sense? Anyway, GetLastError returns 0x0 for all my flags: SE_SECURITY_NAME,SE_BACKUP_NAME and SE_RESTORE_NAME so AdjustTokenPrivileges seems to work fine.. I do not understand why you care so much about SACL, it is required in the project that's all; the question is why CreateFile returns ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD even if SE_SECURITY_NAME is configured?

Comment: for concrete api `AdjustTokenPrivileges` return value have no sense. only `GetLastError`. you say that it 0, but `CreateFile` fail with `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY` and ok without it ? i not believe in this. i ask about sacl - are you really need it or by error ask for `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY`. if you really need access sacl you need `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY` of course. and need have enabled `SE_SECURITY_PRIVILEGE` in token. if `CreateFile` return privilege error - this mean you not enable it. also may be you enable it in process token but your thread have separate token

Comment: I've included one more edit to explain a bit better what is happening.

Comment: you need xor process or thread token use, not both. i think that you fail get `SE_SECURITY_PRIVILEGE` anyway. dump after this privileges in your token or use some tool. test on any another local file - you can open it with `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY` ?

Comment: Added yet another edit to help clearify the issue.

Comment: OpenThreadToken won't do it.  Needs to be OpenProcessToken.  At least, when I tried this, I found OpenThreadToken always failed, but OpenProcessToken at least allowed me to get a proper handle.

Comment: Add checks *everywhere*. You're clearly not even checking if you succeeded opening the token. The thread token *may* do it (contrary to what was written above), however, the typical way is to attempt to open the thread token (which a thread needn't necessarily have) and then fall back to the process token if that didn't work. The convenient part is that you can close both the same way and reuse the `hToken` variable. Since this is a Samba server I'd try that first with a Windows file server to rule out it's a Samba issue, though. Also, are the servers in an AD or standalone?